# When a song slider is held down too long, the positionSlider.value is too big

Tags: swift, xcode, timer, slider, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am somewhat new to Swift.  My song position slider works pretty well.  It is smooth.  The only problem that I've found is that it produces odd results if you hold down the slider in the same spot for too long (pretty much more than a second).  If you do that, you can get a very big number.  There may be a much easier way to handle the slider than I've done here, but this is so close to working.  Thanks for helping!!!

```
var myMPMusicPlayerController = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer
var notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
var sliderInUse: Bool! = false
var positionSliderTimer: Timer!
var songTimer: Timer!
var songDuration: Double!
var positionInSong: Double!

override func viewDidLoad() {
positionSliderTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(PlayerViewController.updatePositionOfSlider), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

// ********** updateSongTimeDisplays() **********
@objc func updateSongTimeDisplays(_ songTime: Double) {

    var currentTime: Int

    if (self.myMPMusicPlayerController.nowPlayingItem != nil)
    {
        if self.sliderInUse == true {
            currentTime = Int(songTime)
        } else {
            currentTime = Int(self.myMPMusicPlayerController.currentPlaybackTime)
        }

        let currentMinutes = currentTime/60
        let currentSeconds = currentTime - currentMinutes * 60
        songElapsedTime.text = NSString(format: "%02d:%02d", currentMinutes,currentSeconds) as String

        let remainingTime = Int(songDuration) - currentTime
        let remaningMinutes = remainingTime/60
        let remainingSeconds = remainingTime - remaningMinutes * 60
        songRemainingTime.text = NSString(format: "%02d:%02d", remaningMinutes,remainingSeconds) as String

    } else {
        // Reset the time to zero.
        songElapsedTime.text = NSString(format: "%02d:%02d", 0,0) as String
    }
}

// ********** positionSliderTapped() **********
@IBAction func positionSliderTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    self.sliderInUse = true
    positionInSong = TimeInterval(positionSlider.value)
    updateSongTimeDisplays(positionInSong)
}

// ********** updatePositionOfSlider() **********
@objc func updatePositionOfSlider() {

    if sliderInUse == false {
        positionSlider.value = Float(self.myMPMusicPlayerController.currentPlaybackTime)
    }
}

// ********** positionSliderReleased() **********
@objc func positionSliderReleased() {

    self.sliderInUse = false
    self.myMPMusicPlayerController.currentPlaybackTime = positionInSong
}
```

The big numbers below happen when I keep my finger in one position after sliding

13
13
13
13
13
13
13
15
16
18
19
20
22
24
26
27
29
30
31
32
32
32
33
33
33
33
33
33
33
33
33
33
95654513522583
33
33
33
33
33
33
33
33
33
33
33
33
95656282321708
33
33
33
33
33
33
33

Answer (score 0):

After further testing and tracing, I figure it out.  When my code explicitly calls updateSongTimeDisplays(_ songTime: Double), there is no problem because I am passing in positionInSong.  But, when iOS calls updateSongTimeDisplays(_ songTime: Double), which it does on the interval, iOS isn't passing in the parameter.  The solution is to not pass in the parameter.  Since positionInSong was declared as part of the class, I don't need to pass it in.  Now, it works perfectly!